# Jcoverflip Custom Code

Tags: jquery

I am using the customized code for Jcoverflip (https://github.com/NewSignature/jcoverflip) from http://it.post80s.com/jquery-auto-play-jcoverflip. It addressed a problem I was having, but after implementing it the images in my carousel do not incrementally decrease in size like they do with the original code seen in the demo at jcoverflip.com. The 2nd, 3rd, etc. images to the left and right of center image are all the same size.

Below is the customized JS, can I modify this to include a decrease in size for the 2nd, 3rd elements out from the center, i.e. add another variable called "otherPicTwo" that applies to these images? All other code is straight from the jcoverflip download.

Thanks for the help, I can modify code decently well but rarely write JS from scratch.

```
/*The center picture has 178px in width*/
var centerPic = 178;

/*Other pictures should have 118px in width*/
var otherPic = 118;

//You can adjust the following position params
var centerPos = 101; var spaceRightCenterLeft = 74;

/* Spaces between pictures/frames */
var spaceOther = 118;
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){

  jQuery( '#flip' ).jcoverflip({
         current: 2,
         time: 600, //animation transition period

         beforeCss: function( el, container, offset ){
            return [
              $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 - (centerPos/2+otherPic) -spaceRightCenterLeft - spaceOther*offset  )+'px', bottom: 0 }, { } ),
              $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { opacity: 0.65, width: otherPic +'px' }, {} )
            ];
          },

          afterCss: function( el, container, offset ){
            return [
              $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 + spaceRightCenterLeft +25 +  spaceOther*offset  )+'px', bottom: 0 }, { } ),
              $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { opacity: 0.65, width: otherPic +'px' }, {} )
            ];
          },

          currentCss: function( el, container ){
            return [
              $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 - centerPos )+'px', bottom: '-38px' }, { } ),
              $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { opacity: 1.0, width: centerPic +'px' }, { } )
            ];
          }  

});
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have not decreased the width of your `li` element every time.  This means it remains the same like you are using width as a variable `otherPic`.

The code below might help you.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){
var videoreelmove = true;
jQuery("#flip").hover(function() { videoreelmove = false;  }, function() {videoreelmove = true;  });
jQuery("#flipnav").hover(function() { videoreelmove = false;  }, function() {videoreelmove = true;  });
setInterval(function() {
    if(videoreelmove) {
    $('#flip').jcoverflip('next', '1', true);
    }
}, 5000);

jQuery( '#flip' ).jcoverflip({
    current: 2,
    time: 600, //animation transition period
    beforeCss: function( el, container, offset ){
    return [
    $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 - 250 - 130*offset -10*offset )+'px', top: '30px' }, { } ),
    $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { width: Math.max(0,130-20*offset*offset) + 'px' }, {} )
    ];
  },
  afterCss: function( el, container, offset ){
     return [
      $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 + 100 + 160*offset + 10*offset)+'px', top: '30px' }, { } ),
      $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { width: Math.max(0,130-20*offset*offset) + 'px' }, {} )
    ];
  },
  currentCss: function( el, container ){
  /*  jQuery('#flip>li.selected').removeClass('selected');
    el.addClass('selected');*/
    return [
      $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 - 90 )+'px', bottom: 0 }, { } ),
      $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { width: '180px' }, { } )
    ];
  },
  change: function(){ $('#flip li:first').appendTo('#flip'); }
});


jQuery('#scrollbar').slider({
  value: 50,
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    if(event.originalEvent) {
      var newVal = Math.round(ui.value/25);
      jQuery( '#flip' ).jcoverflip( 'current', newVal );
      jQuery('#scrollbar').slider('value', newVal*25);
    }
  }
});


 <!-- Navigation buttons-->
 $('.flipnext').click(function(){
     var i = $('#flip').jcoverflip('next');
     i.next();
});

$('.flipprev').click(function(){
     var i = $('#flip').jcoverflip('previous');
             i.next();

});
});
```